# Displaying the name of each module stored in the array ina listBox

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to display the modules names from the array to the listBox but I'm getting a  `"NullReferenceException was unhandled"` error.

**modules.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Modules>
  <Module>
    <MCode>3SFE504</MCode>
    <MName>Algorithms and Data Structures</MName>
    <MCapacity>5</MCapacity>
    <MSemester>1</MSemester>
    <MPrerequisite>None</MPrerequisite>
    <MLectureSlot>0</MLectureSlot>
    <MTutorialSlot>1</MTutorialSlot>
  </Module>

</Modules>
```

**form1.cs**

```
Modules[] modules = new Modules[16];
Modules[] pickedModules = new Modules[8];
int modulecounter = 0, moduleDetailCounter = 0;
while (textReader.Read())
{
    XmlNodeType nType1 = textReader.NodeType;    
    if ((nType1 != XmlNodeType.EndElement) && (textReader.Name == "ModuleList"))
    {    
        // ls_modules_list.Items.Add("MODULE");
        Modules m = new Modules();
        while (textReader2.Read()) //While reader 2 reads the next 7 TEXT items
        {
            XmlNodeType nType2 = textReader2.NodeType;
            if (nType2 == XmlNodeType.Text)
            {
                if (moduleDetailCounter == 0)
                    m.MCode = textReader2.Value;
                if (moduleDetailCounter == 1)
                    m.MName = textReader2.Value;
                if (moduleDetailCounter == 2)
                    m.MCapacity = textReader2.Value;
                if (moduleDetailCounter == 3)
                    m.MSemester = textReader2.Value;
                if (moduleDetailCounter == 4)
                    m.MPrerequisite = textReader2.Value;
                if (moduleDetailCounter == 5)
                    m.MLectureSlot = textReader2.Value;
                if (moduleDetailCounter == 6)
                    m.MTutorialSlot = textReader2.Value;
                // ls_modules_list.Items.Add(reader2.Value);
                moduleDetailCounter++;
            }
            if (moduleDetailCounter == 7) { moduleDetailCounter = 0; break; }

        }
        modules[modulecounter] = m;
        modulecounter++;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < modules.Length; i++)
    {                    
        ModulesListBox.Items.Add(modules[i].MName); // THE ERROR APPEARS HERE
    }
}
```

I'm getting that error on the line  which is marked with `// THE ERROR APPEARS HERE`.

Comment: Try narrowing your problem down, and post *specific* questions. Copy-pasting all your code and asking people to debug it for you isn't the way to go.

Comment: this seems like something much better handled by `XmlSerializer`

Comment: @Attila Kal-El Egemensoy: is there any restriction on using `XmlDocument`?

Answer (score 1):

Either `ModulesListBox` is null because you're accessing it before it is initialized or the `modules` array contains empty elements.

Like one of the commenters said, you're probably better off using XmlSerializer to handle loading the XML into the collection of modules. If that's not possible, change `modules` to a `List<Modules>` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You initialize your modules array to be 16 in length and you load it with the `modulecounter`, but in the loop use the array length.  Instead use the `modulecounter` variable to limit the loop, like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < modulecounter; i++)
{                    
    ModulesListBox.Items.Add(modules[i].MName); 
}
```

Your array is null for every value `modulecounter` and up.  That is why the error.

Answer (score 0):

the for loop runs from 0 to 16 but modules is only 0 to 15, change `modules.length` to (`modules.length -1`)

Comment: still getting the same error, the MName is linked to my ModuleList class and is decalared as "public String MName; "

Comment: The `<` symbol handles the modules.length, but he initializes it to be 16 in length, even if he doesn't load it all up.  See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Almost positive the issue is somewhere with your deserialization logic. One could debug it, but why reinvent the wheel?

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Module>), new XmlRootAttribute("Modules"));
using (var reader = new StreamReader(workingDir + @"\ModuleList.xml"))
    var modules = (List<Module>)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

this would give a nice complete collection of `Module`s assuming it was defined as

```
public class Module
{
    public string MCode;
    public string MName;
    public int MCapacity;
    public int MSemester;
    public string MPrerequisite;
    public int MLectureSlot;
    public int MTutorialSlot;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have no problems with memory (i.e: the file is usually not *too* large), then I suggest not to use `XmlTextReader` and using `XmlDocument` instead:

```
XmlDocument d = new XmlDocument();
d.Load(@"FileNameAndDirectory");
XmlNodeList list = d.SelectNodes("/Modules/Module/MName");
foreach (XmlNode node in list)
{
    // Whatsoever
}
```

The code above should extract every `MName` node for you and put them all in `list`, use it for good :)